# Integrate over geodesic ball on $n$-sphere

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $e_1=(1,0,\dots,0)\in S^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. The geodesic ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $e_1$ is
\begin{align*}
B_\epsilon(e_1) = \{\cos(t)e_1 + \sin(t)v : \lVert v\rVert=1, v_1=0, t\in[0,\epsilon)\}.
\end{align*}
Let $f:S^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R}$ be smooth. **Is the following true?**
\begin{align*}
\int_{B_\epsilon(e_1)}f(p)dp = \int_{S^{n-2}}\int_0^\epsilon f(\varphi(v,t))\sin^n(t)dtdv.
\end{align*}
Here $dp$ is the volume form on $S^{n-1}$ and $dv$ is the volume form on $S^{n-2}\simeq \{v\in S^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^n : v_1=0\}$ (in what follows I identify $v=(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1})\in S^{n-2}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ with $v=(0,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1})\in T_{e_1}S$, the space of unit tangent vectors to $e_1$). I obtained this by considering the diffeomorphism $\varphi:S^{n-2}\times [0,\epsilon)\to B_\epsilon(e_1)$ given by $(v,t)\mapsto \cos(t)e_1+\sin(t)v$ and applying change of variables (see for example Proposition 9.8 [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis6100/diffgeom4.pdf)). At the risk of being overly naive, the derivative of $\varphi$ is
\begin{align*}
D\varphi(v,t) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \cdots & 0 & -sin(t) \\ 
& \sin(t)I_{n-1} & & \vdots \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
which has determinant $-\sin^n(t)$, hence the factor above.